# Rails connect modal with a create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

it's my first post. I'm new in Rails and i need your help. I try to make an online shop.
I have create a button "Buy" (with bootstrap) under each of my products, which activate a modal. Inside modal is a button "Add to cart", and i cant make it work. I want through create action in line_items_controller add a line_item to cart. The modal works fine but the button "Add to cart" no.
I think the problem is the path that i give to button.

My code:

cart.rb

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy
```

line_item.rb

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
      belongs_to :cart
```

product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items
```

line_items_controller.rb

```
class LineItemsController < ApplicationController
  include CurrentCart
  before_action :set_cart, only: [:create]
  before_action :set_line_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

       def create
            @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
            @line_item = create_line_items(@product)
            respond_to do |format|
              if @line_item.save
                format.html { redirect_to @line_item.cart, notice: 'Line item was successfully created.' }
                format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @line_item }
              else
                format.html { render :new }
                format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
              end
            end
          end

      private
        def set_line_item
          @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])
        end

        def line_item_params
          params.require(:line_item).permit(:product_id, :cart_id)
        end
```

app/controllers/concerns/current_cart.rb

```
module CurrentCart
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def create_line_items(product)
     @cart.line_items.build(product: product)
  end

private

  def set_cart 
    @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    @cart = Cart.create
    session[:cart_id] = @cart.id
  end
end
```

the modal in application.html.erb

```
<div class="modal fade" id="buyModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Are you sure you want to buy this?</p>

                <%= button_to 'Add to cart', line_items_path(product_id: @product), :class => "btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-plus", data: {dismiss: "modal"} %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the button 'Buy' which trigger the modal.

views/products/index.html.erb

```
<%= link_to 'Buy', '#', class: "btn btn-success active", data: { toggle: "modal", target: "#buyModal"}  %>
```

I really appreciate any help!

Comment: In your modal, the button should be inside a form and the form should be configured for Ajax with `remote: true`.

Comment: Can you update you logs, After you click on buy ? Where it redirect you?

Comment: No it doesn’t update anything. It should redirect me to card but it does nothing.

Comment: @steveklein you mean something like this: <button type="button" class="btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-plus" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><%= button_to 'Add to cart', line_items_path(product_id: @product), remote: true %></button>

Comment: No Greg.  I would wrap the whole modal in a form which would then get submitted when the button is clicked.  Something like `<%= form_for(@product, remote:true, html: { role: :form, 'data-model' => 'product'}) do %>`.  Not sure whether or not you need those html options, but I have a working modal which includes them.  This should submit product params to your controller when the button is clicked.

Comment: @steveklein I update the code with the following but i got an error "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty":  `<%= form_for(@product, remote:true, html: { role: :form, 'data-model' => 'product'}) do %>
   <%= button_to 'Add to cart', line_items_path(product_id: @product), :class => "btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-plus", data: {dismiss: "modal"} %>
<% end %>`

Comment: Sounds like `@product` is not defined.  You'll need to set it in your controller action if you need it in your view (you are referencing it in your button).

Comment: @steveklein but i have define it . Look at the code that i have post above.

Comment: Then it is not defined correctly.  You'll need to debug what is happening in your controller and make sure `@product` is getting populated as expected.  Generally, if you are using Rails 4+, you should avoid accessing the params hash directly in your actions but instead define parameter access as you did in your controller for `line_item_params`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to me for method type. Try use ':method => :post' with button_to tag.

```
<%= button_to 'Add to cart', line_items_path(product_id: @product), :method => :post, :class => "btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-plus", data: {dismiss: "modal"} %>
```

Comment: @Dipak, isn't a form needed?  Not sure how submit will work without a form wrapping it unless it is just a fake submit with JS.

Comment: It seems to me doable without form. Like we did for delete action.